# MongoDB aggregate - How to use in PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

I use this command in MongoDB and it returns correct data:

```php
db.getCollection('school').aggregate([{ $group: { _id: "$initials", total: { $sum: "$total" }}}, { $sort : { _id : 1}}])
```

But when I write that command in PHP, I get error. I am trying:

```php
$mng = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager();
$command = new MongoDB\Driver\Command(['aggregate' => 'school', 'pipeline' => [ '$group' => ['_id' => '$initials', 'count' => [ '$sum' => '$total']], 'cursor' => new stdClass ]]);
$cursor = $mng->executeCommand('school', $command);
var_dump($cursor->toArray()[0]);
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\CommandException: 'pipeline' option must be specified as an array in /var/www/html/mongodbtest.php:45

Comment: try `$command = new MongoDB\Driver\Command(['aggregate' => 'school', 'pipeline' => [[ '$group' => ['_id' => '$initials', 'count' => [ '$sum' => '$total']]], 'cursor' => new stdClass ]]);` (pipeline expects array of "commands", each of them should be array)

Answer (score 0):

Now it is correct:

```php
$command = new MongoDB\Driver\Command(['aggregate' => 'school', 'pipeline' => [[ '$group' => ['_id' => '$initials', 'count' => [ '$sum' => '$total']]], [ '$sort' => ['_id' => 1] ],], 'cursor' => new stdClass, ]);
```

Thanks